# Mapping dead keys like "^"

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I'm currently rebinding almost all of my Emacs bindings to fit my new keyboard layout, bépo, a french equivalent of dvorak.

I'm having trouble mapping my `^` key. The `^` key is a dead key but not at a material level.

I'd like to be able to to map `C-^` but currently, it don't work. Because "dead-circumflex" and "circumflex" are two different keys.

If I do:

```
(global-set-key "C-^" 'next-line)
```

Then, pressing control key with "^" key does the following:

```
 <C-dead-circumflex> is undefined
```

We have the proof emacs see the dead-circumflex. But I still can't manage to map it.

I know that I can do

```
(global-set-key "^" 'next-line)
```

, and that it will work by pressing `^` twice, but it's not the workaround I'm searching for.

Comment: What OS and GUI are you using? (e.g. Windows 7, OSX/Aqua, FreeBSD/KDE, …)

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint 11, with gnome 2. I use Emacs 23.2.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message tells you what name Emacs uses for the key.  You can pass that string to the `kbd` function to bind it.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<C-dead-circumflex>") 'next-line)
```

Comment: But you have to manually find and bind each dead key in that way. Lars' solution sets everything automatically in one line.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same annoying error, but only when using the emacs GUI, not from the terminal.
The problem with the proposed solution is that ^ isn't the only character not working. For me it was at least ` and ' as well.

From this thread: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=918740 I found that changing XMODIFIERS from "@im=ibus" to "" solved the issue. While searching where XMODIFIERS where set I stubled across the following issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1125944
It turns out that by removing ~/.config/ibus/bus which solves that issue also solves the issue in emacs with dead keys

```
rm -rf ~/.config/ibus/bus
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the following to your `~/.emacs`:

```
(require 'iso-transl)
```

This takes care of the problem with undefined [dead keys](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DeadKeys).

Comment: this did for me, thanks! (this is with Emacs 24.5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 where I have no admin rights)

Comment: Are you sure this fixes `<C-dead-circumflex>`? Didn't work for me. Setting XMODIFIERS to empty did it, but I like the other mode because it shows the dead key before pressing the following letter.